# Parse.com JSON-import: 'rows can't be more than 128kb'

Tags: json, parse-platform

I have a JSON-file which looks like this:

```
{"results" : [{"animals" :{"dog" : {"height" : .......}},"cat" : {"height" : .......}}]}
```

A lot more nesting is done, but I guess this is the important part. The problem is when I'm trying to import this file as a JSON-file in parse, it imports, but doesn't add any rows, claiming "rows can't be larger than 128 kb" when my file is only 106 kb. Also, I'm guessing it should create 2 rows from the example above?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an *entire* Parse object is 128 KB - you're most likely hitting the limit when you include the *keys* as well.